# 404 Error in Custom Magento Module

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404

I am using Magento 1.6.2.0 and I’m facing a 404 problem for one custom module that I can’t seem to fix.  All of my other custom modules work except for this one which shows a more detailed status view of an order. What is the most perplexing part is that I have an installation of magento with this custom module working perfectly on a server, but I can’t seem to get it to work on this new server.

I’ve checked the permissions, no problem.  I’ve checked the logs but there is no meaningful information other than httpd telling me there is a 404 error page not found. I’ve ruled out my controller as being the problem. I've done a lot of searching and i know there are many responses to 404 errors in magento.  I've tried several attempts at fixing this with the current documentation out there to no avail.

I've posted my config.xml below.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciate because I’m getting my butt kicked.  I’ll answer any questions promptly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ciplex_Giftango>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Ciplex_Giftango>
    </modules>

        <global>

            <helpers><giftango><class>Ciplex_Giftango_Helper</class></giftango></helpers>

          <blocks><giftango><class>Ciplex_Giftango_Block</class></giftango></blocks>
            <blocks>
                <adminhtml>
                    <rewrite>
                        <sales_order>Ciplex_Giftango_Block_Sales_Order</sales_order>
                        <sales_order_grid>Ciplex_Giftango_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                    </rewrite>
                </adminhtml>
            </blocks>

            <template>
                <email>
                    <resellers_email_template>
                        <label>eGift Card Delivery</label>
                        <file>resellers_email_template.html</file>
                        <type>html</type>
                    </resellers_email_template>
                </email>
            </template>

        </global>



        <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <giftango>Ciplex_Giftango_Adminhtml</giftango>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>


        <adminhtml>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <giftango><file>giftango.xml</file></giftango>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: have you tried using `<giftango before="Mage_Adminhtml">...</giftango>` in admin/routers/adminhtml/args/modules xml path?

Answer (score 0):

Please clear your browser cache if some times before custom module is working but due to some change it might be given 404 error

or there are some solution which is very useful in [magento commerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/78080/)

Answer (score 0):

try by adding "index.php" in your url.

For example: http://example.com/index.php/helloworld/index/index

If you are done with this. Search some article to remove index.php from magento.